# стрелки в виндоус

Tags: c, windows, curses

Как организовать передвижение курсора в Windows, Си, Pdcurses?

Хочу, чтобы моя прога (https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/sudoku - передвижение курсора запрограммированы в файле cursor.c) работала под виндой, но столкнулся с проблемой: при нажатии на стрелки прога не видит что какие-то клавиши вообще нажимаются! Даже мини прогу создал для теста:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main (void) 
{
    initscr();

    int a, b, c;

    a = getch();
    b = getch();
    c = getch();

    printw ("%d %d %d", a, b, c);

    getch();

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

при запуске на Линуксе, если нажать стрелку, то она выдает 3 цифры, а на Windows - вообще не реагирует при нажатии стрелки.

PS на линуксе используется ncurses, а на винде - pdcurses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будучи скомпилирован VC++ 2015, код

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

    int a, b, c, d;

    a = getch();
    b = getch();
    c = getch();
    d = getch();

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d);

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Совершенно честно отрабатывает нажатие стрелок. Вы же помните, что extended keys, к которым относятся и стрелки, генерируют **два** кода, принимаемые двумя последовательными вызовами `getch()`?

Так, нажатие стрелок влево и вправо дает

```
224 75 224 77
```

а их же на дополнительной цифровой клавиатуре -

```
0 75 0 77
```

Comment: разве не три? Типа 27 91 и третья определяющая 65-68.

Comment: Возможно, в последних навороченных клавиатурах и три - со времен DOS в общем-то, не интересовался этим вопросом. Но для стандартных 101 или сколько их там клавишных - всегда хватало двух.

Comment: разобрался с этим: в Линуксе выдает 3, а в винде - 2. Со своим вопросом тоже разобрался - оказывается Pdcurses напроч не видит стрелок, но ты навел меня на мысль использовать conio.h. Пришлось основательно поизвозится, чтобы эти две библиотеки не конфликтовали, но у меня все получилось)